# css have a body margin but div to span 100% over margin

Tags: html, css

as the heading say. I have a margin on my body tag, this I want. but would like to have a div span across the screen width over the margins.

```
body{
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}

#banner{
background-color:#000;
width:100%;
margin-left:-10px;
}
```

This gives me my black div over the left margin, how would I get it to span over the right?
I have tried to apply a margin on the right, this had no effect on the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just using the margin on the body to add spacing around your page, I would suggest switching it for padding instead.

Then you can position the banner back out against the edges of the browser window (instead of the body edge) like this:

Try this:

```
#banner{
    background-color:#000;
    width:auto;
    margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

assuming that #banner is a block-level element, it should then flow full-width, including the 10px either side.  If it's not (ie: if it's a span), also add `display: block` to the CSS above.

See my JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gwfKz/

Comment: still have the same effect. it moves the div the 10px to left over the margin but have a 20px gap to the right.

Comment: If you're just using the margin on the body to create space, I'd suggest you consider using padding instead?  I'll update my answer for you..

Comment: using the padding works as well, but the width of the banner still ends before the right. however, when adding position:absolute to the code the banner spans right across, but all site content moves up. The site is responsive, so when changing the browser size all content then hides under the banner

Comment: Position:absolute will position #banner off the nearest relatively-positioned parent.  It sounds more likely that you've got a validation issue somewhere in your HTML.  Try running the page through the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and correct anything that comes back from that.  After that, my suggestion above should work.

Comment: found the issue, thanx for the assistance.